# Tarpana mantras and their literal meaning word by word

Tags: mantras, translation-request, sraddha, pitru

I wanted to understand the tarpana mantras all inclusive after sankalpam ... starting from asking the pitrus to sit on koorcha and giving the manes oblations to asking them to leave and come when ever invited

Answer (score 4):

P.V.R Narasimha Rao uploaded PDFs [in his website here](http://www.vedicastrologer.org/tarpana/index.htm) which describe simple yet complete methods of doing Pitru Tarpana.

You can download one such PDF from [here](http://www.vedicastrologer.org/tarpana/pdf/tarpana_english_s.pdf) (it is describing the process in short).

First we have to do the Sankalpam like this:

> om adya çubha dine çubha muhürte devarñipitåprétyarthaà
> devarñipitåtarpaëam yathäçakti kariñye|
>
> on this auspicious day and auspicious time, I shall perform tarpana to
> Devas, Rishis and Pitris to the best of my ability”. After reciting
> it, the akshatas are dropped on the ground in front of one.

Then we have to Do Deva-Rishi-Pitru Tarpanas in that order.

- Deva Tarapana Mantras:

  Invocation-

> brahmäadayaù suräù sarve åñayaù kaçyapädayaù| ägacchantu mahäbhägä
> brahmäëòodaravartinaù||
>
> may Brahma etc gods and Kashyapa etc sages, may all the great ones who
> live in the stomach of the cosmic egg of creation come here

And the individual Mantras are like:

> om brahmä trpyatäm| om viñëuù trpyatäm| om rudraù trpyatäm| om
> prajäpatiù trpyatäm| om deväù trpyantäm| om devyaù trpyantäm| om
> vasavaù trpyantäm| om rudräù trpyantäm| om ädityäù trpyantäm| om
> chandäàsi trpyantäm| om vedäù trpyantäm| om åñayaù trpyantäm| om
> gandharväù trpyantäm| om apsarasaù trpyantäm| om devänugäù trpyantäm|
> om nägäù trpyantäm| om sägaräù trpyantäm| om parvatäù trpyantäm| om
> saritaù trpyantäm| om manuñyäù trpyantäm| om yakñäù trpyantäm| om
> rakñäàsi trpyantäm| om piçäcäù trpyantäm| om suparëäù trpyantäm| om
> bhütäni trpyantäm| om paçavaù trpyantäm| om vanaspatayaù trpyantäm| om
> oñadhayaù trpyantäm|

Nothing to translate here. "Trypantam" simply means "satisfying or appeasing".

- Rishi Tarpana Mantras:

> om kaçyapaù trpyatäm| om atriù trpyatäm| om vasiñöhaù trpyatäm| om
> viçvämitraù trpyatäm| om gautamaù trpyatäm| om bharadväjaù trpyatäm|
> om jamadagniù trpyatäm| om aìgéräù trpyatäm| om kutsaù trpyatäm| om
> bhåguù trpyatäm|

Then comes Divya Manushya Tarpanam, Divya Pitru Tarpana and Yama Tarpana. (omitting these details).

- Pitru Tarpana Mantras:

  Invocation-

> om ägacchantu me pitaraù imaà gåhëantu jaläïjalim|
>
> may my ancestors come here and accept my water oblations
>
> mama sarvajanmeñu pitaraù trpyantäm idaà tilodakaà svadhäyibhyaù
> tebhyaù svadhä namaù ||1|| tebhyaù svadhä namah ||2|| tebhyaù svadhä
> namah ||3|
>
> (To beings who played the role of father in various lives to you)

There is nothing to translate in these Mantras actually. Tilodaka = Til (sesame seeds) + Udaka (water) which is used as the offering. Pita meaning father.

> mama sarvajanmeñu pitämahäù trpyantäm idaà tilodakaà svadhäyibhyaù
> tebhyaù svadhä namaù ||1|| tebhyaù svadhä namah ||2|| tebhyaù svadhä
> namah ||3||| (To beings who played the role of father’s father in
> various lives to you)

Pitamaha=Father's father.

Similarly, there are other Mantras like:

> mama sarvajanmeñu mätaraù trpyantäm idaà tilodakaà svadhäyibhyaù
> täbhyaù svadhä namaù ||1|| täbhyaù svadhä namah ||2|| täbhyaù svadhä
> namah ||3| (To beings who played the role of mother in various lives
> to you)

and,

> mama sarvajanmeñu pitämahyaù trpyantäm idaà tilodakaà svadhäyibhyaù
> täbhyaù svadhä namah ||1|| täbhyaù svadhä namah ||2|| täbhyaù svadhä
> namah ||3||| (To beings who played the role of father’s mother in
> various lives to you)

Pitamahi=Father's mother.

and so on..

There are also other methods of Tarpana where "Tarpayami" is used instead of "Tripyantam" in the Mantras.

Comment: Thanks for the details, i was looking for answers for Udheerathamvara uthparasa,

Unmadhyama pithara somyasa

Asum ya eeyuravyaka ruthagna

Sthene avanthu pitharo harveshu... for Vasu, rudra and aditya similarly

Comment: @somebodynobody There are actually more than one methods of performing it and so the mantras will change accordingly. Do u know from where are u quoting the mantras u mentioned? I only know 2 such methods-one already given in the answer and another one which is from a Purana.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but i got this from the nitya tarpana mantras for srivaishanavas, tengalai sect... I was intruded more about the meaning of these mantras.. any clarifications would be of great help

Comment: In the above pdf, there is no mention of offering 'naivedyam' to pitras. In shortcut tarpan also, I have seen people offering something like 'kheer'. Anybody knows how to do it and mantras for it? (Sprinkling water around offering is in anti-clockwise manner I think)..Then regarding offering 'asanas' (seats) for devata, rishi and pitra?

Comment: I think it's better to follow him completely or not follow him at all. It is not recommended that you pick some stuffs from this Panditji and some other from others. AFAIK, this Punditji is learned in scriptures and there's no risk in following his tutorial @Vineet

Comment: No doubt about this. What I meant to say is -- That pdf deals with 'Tarpanam' which is a part of 'Shradhha'. 'Shradhha' has got much more rituals and mantras. I don't intend to challenge him or show any flaw.