# Shraddha performance by host (himself)

Tags: rituals, sraddha

Whether 'Shraddha' can be performed by the 'yajaman' (host) himself if he is a Brahmin?
The purpose of asking this is now a days it is difficult to get a Brahmin who performs this 'sincerely', devoting proper time and uttering clear pronunciation of mantras.

Can anybody please cite the full Sanskrit text for chanting during Shraddha?

There is a [similar question here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9871/what-would-be-the-authentic-source-for-%C5%9Ar%C4%81ddha-vidhi)

But it does not contain any sanskrit script and detailed procedure; it has a link to wiki page for "Ghriya Sutras" and a checklist pdf where there is no detail of actual vidhi.

Comment: If same question is asked but there is no answer is present, it is still duplicate and there shouldn't be repetition of questions.

Comment: The question is not exact duplicate. First part of question is totally different than 'similar question' elsewhere.

Comment: You may find my answer helpful. Check the PDFs linked in my answer. They have the procedures in details. @Vineet https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26829/tarpana-mantras-and-their-literal-meaning-word-by-word/26836#26836

Comment: @Rickross , great. I was looking for it. (I couldn't find it because it doesn't contain the word 'shraddha'). Anyways.... That answers my second part of original question.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes it's very helpful for those who want to do it on their own. Also, there are short procedures as well as lengthy ones given. One can choose as per his wish. @Vineet

Comment: I have downloaded all 3 versions. Will study and follow a suitable one. Thanks.

Comment: Once I heard (reliably)  that a very young brahmin priest mistakenly recited shraddha manthras in an auspicious  ceremony of mother /new born baby and it later resulted in the baby's death. So it is believed it should be very carefully done.

Comment: In the above pdf, there is no mention of offering 'naivedyam' to pitras. In shortcut tarpan also, I have seen people offering something like 'kheer'. Anybody knows how to do it and mantras for it? (Sprinkling water around offering is in anti-clockwise manner I think)..Then regarding offering 'asanas' (seats) for devata, rishi and pitra?

Comment: If yo want to learn total vidhi from a pdf or the internet, that is an almost impossible task. It should be done by practice in real time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shraddha can be performed even by a Shudra too. In fact, as per the Smritis, it is one of the only two religious rites, that he is allowed to perform. So, it does not require the performer to be only a Brahmin to be considered qualified.

From the Yajnavalkya Smriti's (YS) Chapter 1:

> [He should be](i.e a Shudra should be) devotedly attached to his wife,
>   be of pure conduct, a protector of servants **and given to the
>   performance of Sraddha**. With the recitation of the Mantra "Namas", he
>   should perform the five Yajnas.
>
> **YS 1.121**

The performance of Shraddha requires reciting the Mantra "Swadha" and it is a Mantra which can be uttered by everyone, even by the uninitiates as the following verse shows:

> Manu Smriti 2.172. (He who has not been initiated) should not
>   pronounce (any) Vedic text **excepting (those required for) the
>   performance of funeral rites**, since he is on a level with a Sudra
>   before his birth from the Veda.

So, anyone, who knows how to do it correctly, can perform Shraddah on their own. There's no prohibition on that. But, it is better to appoint a Brahmin, in case when one does not know about the procedures at all.

We do not do it not because we aren't qualified but because we think an appointed Brahmin can do it more accurately than us. Because, most people may not be even aware of the correct procedures.